# How to save go.FigureWidget as html (plotly, python)?

Tags: python, plotly

I want to save go.FigureWidget as html (not go.Figure).
If I use 'write_html', sliders of go.Figure works well,  but when I use click event (.on_click) of go.scatter3d, click event of html file doesn't works.

When I use go.FigureWidget in jupyter notebook, it works well.

Is there any way to save as html with callback funcions of .py module?